# Selenium Python Firefox webdriver : can't modify profile

Tags: python, firefox, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use, on a webdriver Firefox instance, the  "new tab instead of window" option.
1/ I created a profile with this option on, but when I use the profile a lot of options are OK but not this one.
2/ After the load of the profile I tried to change the option in the code but it does n't work.
My code :

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(os.path.join(s_path, name))
profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction", 0)
profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3)
profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_external", 3)
profile.set_preference("browser.startup.homepage","http://www.google.fr")
profile.update_preferences()
print(os.path.join(s_path, name))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(set_profile())
```

All is OK (the start homepage is google.fr) except this option which is not OK.

It seems that Selenium copy the profile in a temp dir. where users.js have the wrong line :

```
user_pref("browser.link.open_newwindow", 2);
```

Python 3.4.2, Windows 7, Firefox 39.0, Selenium lib 2.46

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've researched, `browser.link.open_newwindow` is a **frozen setting** and it's always synced with the value `2`. If you dig up the source of the selenium Python bindings, you would find a [set of `frozen` settings](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py#95) that is applied after your custom settings are set.

Note that in [`java` bindings](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.java?r=1bbc3c953fc70b7a9865ce82119bb4423db71606) this set of default frozen settings is explicitly hardcoded:

```
  /**
   * Profile preferences that are essential to the FirefoxDriver operating correctly. Users are not
   * permitted to override these values.
   */
  private static final ImmutableMap<String, Object> FROZEN_PREFERENCES =
      ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
          .put("app.update.auto", false)
          .put("app.update.enabled", false)
          .put("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false)
          .put("browser.EULA.override", true)
          .put("browser.EULA.3.accepted", true)
          .put("browser.link.open_external", 2)
          .put("browser.link.open_newwindow", 2)  // here it is
          // ...
```

And a bit of an explanation coming from [Firefox only supports windows not tabs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3380):

> This is a known issue and unfortunately we will not be supporting tabs.
>
> We force Firefox to open all links in a new window. We can't access
>   the tabs to know when to switch. When we move to marionette (Mozilla
>   project) in the future we should be able to do this but for now it is
>   working as intended

A workaround solution would be to [change the `target` of a link manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26122957/771848) - may not work in all of the cases depending on how a new link is opened.

Comment: Nice answer, for my own use, I prefered to change the json file : \Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver_prefs.json where the frozen lines are defined...

Answer (score 3):

`"browser.link.open_newwindow"` is a **frozen** preference, which means that it *can't* be modified using `profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 3)`

**The solution** is to use `profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES["frozen"]["browser.link.open_newwindow"] = 3` instead. (the other non-frozen preferences can be set with `set_preference` without problem)