# Firefox custom profile doesn't work [Python]

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to set a custom profile for Firefox using Selenium module. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class oo1():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def fps(self):
        print 'running fp'
        self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        self.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', '1')
        self.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', 'true')
        self.profile.set_preference('network.cookie.cookieBehaviour', '2')
        self.profile.set_preference('javascript.enabled', 'False')
        self.profile.update_preferences()
    def driverr(self):
        print 'running'
        self.web = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=self.profile)
        self.web.get(self.url)


s = oo1('127.0.0.1')
s.fps()
s.driverr()
```

When I run the above code, Firefox runs properly but none of the settings that I wrote above are applied to the Firefox.

What is the problem and How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues here:

- the setting is called `network.cookie.cookieBehavior` (no `u` there)
- `javascript.enabled` is a [*frozen preference*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31384526/selenium-python-firefox-webdriver-cant-modify-profile) and cannot be changed

Fixed version:

```
self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
self.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
self.profile.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_remote_dns', True)
self.profile.set_preference('network.cookie.cookieBehavior', 2)
self.profile.set_preference('javascript.enabled', False)
self.profile.update_preferences()
```